# Initiate truncate, then write

Tags: mysql, pdo, myisam

If I initiate a `TRUNCATE` on a table, what happens to `INSERT`s executed against that table? Are they queued until the `TRUNCATE` completes, or are they simply discarded? I know this condition is quite rare but it's possible.

I'm using PDO transactions with MySQL, however I have to `TRUNCATE` the table after the transaction. I don't want to use `DELETE` from within the transaction as it's slower than `TRUNCATE`. This is for a stats logger on a website, so concurrent requests to the same table are easily possible.

The queries executed are (from the query log):

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter FROM stats_current
START TRANSACTION
LOCK TABLES stats_current WRITE, stats WRITE
UNLOCK TABLES
LOCK TABLES stats_customer_current WRITE, stats_customer WRITE
UNLOCK TABLES
LOCK TABLES stats_update_queue WRITE, stats_customer_current WRITE, stats_customer WRITE
UNLOCK TABLES
TRUNCATE stats_update_queue
commit
```

Comment: You are talking about transactions but tagged your question `MyISAM`? You know that MyISAM is not a transactional engine?

Comment: I do, yes. I think I'm confusing MySQL transactions with PDO transactions?